Is using KNN Imputation Method make sense in handling missing values for a wind forecast datasets?
I have a datasets called full_weather.csv with various features. I have dropped some columns that does not correlate with wind forecasting and I have found a lots of NaN ( null values in some of the columns ). Does using KNN-Imputation make sense to handle those missing continuous values ?
I have already tried methods like mean but the mse show a significant amount which I am not happy about.
I am opt for KNN-Imputation but the code takes too much time to run.
# K-Nearest Neighbour Imputation 
df_knn = df.copy(deep=True)
knn_imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2, weights="uniform")
print("Loading...")
df_knn['temperature'] = knn_imputer.fit_transform(df_knn[['temperature']])
print(df_knn['temperature'].isnull().sum())

The output of the print does not came out. Did I miss any parts of the imputation ?
